# How to check the state of a dynamically generated JCheckBox in an action listener

Tags: java, swing

I have created dynamic JChekboxes that is linked to a file. I want to see which ones are checked via an action listener. I have tried getSource(), I have tried getState() none of them are working...

```
for (int f = 0; f < numberCheckBox[0]; f++) {
            String line1 = tableLines[f].toString().trim();
            String[] dataRow1 = line1.split("/");
            checkBoxList[f] = new JCheckBox(Arrays.toString(dataRow1).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
            Checkp.add(checkBoxList[f]);
            System.out.print(checkBoxList[f]);
        }

         save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(files));
                Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();
                numberCheckBox[0] = tableLines.length;
                for (int j = 0; j < numberCheckBox[0]; j++) {
                    if(e.getSource() == finalCheckBoxList[j]){
                        if(e.getStateChange() == 1){

                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: All you need to do is get the source of the ActionEvent and cast that object to a JCheckBox. Then you can use the getText() method. No need to check the state.

Comment: Well, you might want to use `isSelected` to determine if the button is checked or not

Comment: I did use isSelected and it did not work as well.

Comment: @boualpso Then you're doing something wrong, because `isSelected` works just fine for me and is best solution for finding the current selected state of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you'll want to do is check out [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

So from the [`JCheckBox` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected())

> **isSelected**
>
> ```
> public boolean isSelected()
> ```
>
> Returns the state of the
> button. True if the toggle button is selected, false if it's not.
> **Returns:**
> true if the toggle button is selected, otherwise false

In addition, if you need some way to pass information to the `ActionListener`.  You could continue to rely on the `index` of the values, but I always prefer to encapsulate this information if possible.

So, in this example, I've used both the `actionCommand` and `clientProperty` methods to seed the information I might want to use in the `ActionListener`

> I did use isSelected and it did not work as well.

Then you're doing something wrong, because the below example works just fine

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            int[] numberCheckBox = new int[] { 5 };
            JCheckBox[] checkBoxList = new JCheckBox[5];
            String[] tableLines = new String[] {
                "this/is/a/test",
                "hello/world",
                "something/wicked/this/way/comes",
                "a/long/long/time/ago",
                "i/have/something/to/say",
            };

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            for (int f = 0; f < numberCheckBox[0]; f++) {
                String line1 = tableLines[f].toString().trim();
                String[] dataRow1 = line1.split("/");                
                checkBoxList[f] = new JCheckBox(String.join(", ", dataRow1));
                checkBoxList[f].setActionCommand(line1);
                checkBoxList[f].putClientProperty("value", line1);
                add(checkBoxList[f], gbc);
                System.out.print(checkBoxList[f]);
            }

            JButton save = new JButton("Save");
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            add(save, gbc);

            save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    for (JCheckBox cb : checkBoxList) {
                        if (cb.isSelected()) {
                            System.out.println("Action Command = " + cb.getActionCommand());
                            System.out.println("Client Property = " + (String)cb.getClientProperty("value"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it